# (PYOMO)I want to put constraint of limiting daily production in pyomo constraint

Tags: pyomo

I have endeavored this problem which was an easy solution in GAMS file but I cannot do it with PYOMO.

My problem is that I would like to put a limit in production as a daily basis as a constraint for a certain generation.

The generation is variable with 8760 hourly set and summation of this generation per day should be lower than certain limit.

In GAMS, I can easily solve it with following code;

```
set t hours in a year /1*8760/ ;   
set d day /1*365/;
```

#### I make parameter day(t) for spliting hours in a year

```
parameter day(t) ;
day(t)$(ord(t) <= 24)=1;
day(t)$(ord(t)>24 and mod(ord(t),24) ne 0)=round(ord(t)/24-mod(ord(t),24)/24)+1;
day(t)$(ord(t)>24 and mod(ord(t),24) eq 0)= ord(t)/24;
```

#### with the sets and paramter day(t) I can make following equation as constraint

```
hydro_day(d)..sum(t$(day(t)=ord(d)),hydro_el(t))=l=6*spec('Hydro', 'cap');
```

In Pyomo, I have tried as follow but it doesn't work for now

```
def dcap_rule(model)  :
    dailyLimit = {}
    for k in range(365) :
        dailyLimit[k] = sum(model.discharge[i] for i in sequence((24*(k-1)+1), 24*k)) 
        return dailyLimit[k]<= model.capa['pumped']*5 
model.dcap_limit = Constraint( rule=dcap_rule)
```

This code only applied to the first day(1-24hours) then after the first day, there seems to be no constraint .

Could you help me solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring a scalar constraint, so only one constraint is being generated.  You want to change your code to generate an *indexed* constraint:

```
def dcap_rule(model, k):
   return sum(model.discharge[i] for i in sequence((24*(k-1)+1), 24*k)) \
       <= model.capa['pumped']*5 
model.dcap_limit = Constraint(range(365), rule=dcap_rule)
```